# Cambiar formato ancho-largo en tabla de excel sin formato apropiado

Tags: r, tidyverse

Tengo un archivo excel de este estilo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
structure(list(Territorio = c("Aguadulce", "Alanís", "Albaida del Aljarafe", 
"Alcalá de Guadaíra", "Alcalá del Río", "Alcolea del Río", 
"Algaba (La)", "Algámitas", "Almadén de la Plata"), `2007` = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), `2008` = c(10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 
17, 18), `2009` = c(19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27), `2010` = c(28, 
29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36), `2011` = c(37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 
42, 43, 44, 45), `2012` = c(46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54
)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))-> datos
```

Lo cambio a formato largo

```
library(tidyr)

dat_nuevos = gather(datos, key = Año, value = Valores, -Territorio)
```

pero ¿cómo lo hago cuando los datos son de este estilo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
structure(list(...1 = c("Territorio", "Aguadulce", "Alanís", 
"Albaida del Aljarafe", "Alcalá de Guadaíra", "Alcalá del Río", 
"Alcolea del Río", "Algaba (La)", "Algámitas", "Almadén de la Plata"
), Industria = c("2007", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
"9"), ...3 = c("2008", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", 
"17", "18"), ...4 = c("2009", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
"25", "26", "27"), Energia = c("2007", "28", "29", "30", "31", 
"32", "33", "34", "35", "36"), ...6 = c("2008", "37", "38", "39", 
"40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45"), ...7 = c("2009", "46", "47", 
"48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Una observación al margen de tu pregunta. La función `gather()` ha sido sustituida por `pivot_longer()`. Entiendo que es preferible usar la segunda opción: https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/gather.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asumo que tus datos tienen exactamente la misma estructura que en el ejemplo y que así salen de leer el Excel. Como suele ser en la limpieza de datos, las soluciones son muy ad hoc a los datos. Aunque admito que este caso de variables mal nombradas en Excel es endémico.

Esta es la solución que encontré. Es larga y enredada y habría que validar con mucho cuidado los datos resultantes porque podría fallar de muchas maneras.

Llamo a los datos problemáticos `datos2`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)
datos2 %>% 
  set_names(paste(names(.), .[1 , ])) %>% 
  slice(-1) %>%
  janitor::clean_names() %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = - x1_territorio) %>%   
  separate(name, into = c("rubro", "año"), sep = "_") %>%  
  mutate(rubro = ifelse(str_detect(rubro, "x"), NA, rubro)) %>% 
  fill(rubro)
```

Obtengo el resultado:

```
# A tibble: 54 × 4
   x1_territorio rubro     año   value
   <chr>         <chr>     <chr> <chr>
 1 Aguadulce     industria 2007  1    
 2 Aguadulce     industria 2008  10   
 3 Aguadulce     industria 2009  19   
 4 Aguadulce     energia   2007  28   
 5 Aguadulce     energia   2008  37   
 6 Aguadulce     energia   2009  46   
 7 Alanís        industria 2007  2    
 8 Alanís        industria 2008  11   
 9 Alanís        industria 2009  20   
10 Alanís        energia   2007  29
```

El código comentado:

```
datos2 %>% 
  set_names(paste(names(.), .[1 , ])) %>%  #Pego en los nombres el nombre y el año, que está en la primera fila.
  slice(-1) %>%                            #Elimino la primera fila, no tiene datos sino nombres de variables. Ya están en los nombres. 
  janitor::clean_names() %>%               #Limpio los nombres para sacar espacios y puntos
  pivot_longer(cols = - x1_territorio) %>%   #Paso a formato largo, se podría usar gather. 
  separate(name, into = c("rubro", "año"), sep = "_") %>%    #Separo los nombres que unen dos cosas (rubro y año) en dos columnas.
  mutate(rubro = ifelse(str_detect(rubro, "x"), NA, rubro)) %>%   #Paso a NA los rubros que no tienen información útil. Como todos tiene la con x uso una simple expresión regular. Si algún rubro válido tuviera una x habría que usar una regex más compleja.
  fill(rubro, .direction = "down")          #fill rellena NAs con el último dato válido. Explicito de arriba hacia abajo, aunque es así por defecto.
```

## Bonus

Con `pivot_wider` es fácil pasarlos de nuevo a formato ancho, con nombres de columna correctos.

```
datos3 %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(rubro, año), values_from = value)
```