# Cambiar estructura de datos al cargar un excel

Tags: r

Parto de unos datos como estos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y quiero llegar a esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Supongo que el procedimiento tiene que ser similar a esta solución para una [pregunta parecida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/520945/cambiar-formato-ancho-largo-en-tabla-de-excel-sin-formato-apropiado?noredirect=1#comment925038_520945), pero que no logro modificalo para llegar a lo que quiero.

Datos

```
structure(list(...1 = c("Ciudad", "ciudad1", "ciudad2", "ciudad3", 
"ciudad4"), `2000` = c("Hombres", "1", "2", "3", "4"), ...3 = c("Mujeres", 
"5", "6", "7", "8"), `2001` = c("Hombres", "9", "10", "11", "12"
), ...5 = c("Mujeres", "13", "14", "15", "16"), `2002` = c("Hombres", 
"17", "18", "19", "20"), ...7 = c("Mujeres", "21", "22", "23", 
"24")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Otro batch `tidyverse`

```
df %>% 
  setNames(
    c(.[1, 1, drop = TRUE], 
      paste(
        rep(names(.[, -1])[seq(1, length(names(.[, -1])), 2)], each = 2),
        .[1, -1])
    )    
  ) %>% 
  slice(-1) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Ciudad) %>% 
  separate(name, into = c('Año', 'Sexo')) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Sexo,
              values_from = value)
```

La parte más compleja es "limpiar" los nombres de columna, básicamente, repetimos los valores de año y los combinamos con los dos valores de sexo de la primer fila:

```
df %>% 
  setNames(
    c(.[1, 1, drop = TRUE], 
      paste(
        rep(names(.[, -1])[seq(1, length(names(.[, -1])), 2)], each = 2),
        .[1, -1])
    )    
  ) %>% 
  names()
[1] "Ciudad"       "2000 Hombres" "2001 Mujeres" "2002 Hombres"
[5] "2000 Mujeres" "2001 Hombres" "2002 Mujeres"
```

Lo que resta es más simple: 1) transformamos a un formato "largo", 2) dividimos la columna en `Año` y `Sexo` 3) Llevamos `Sexo` al formato ancho.

Answer (score 3):

Sigue una solución:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)

datos <- datos %>% 
  set_names(paste(names(.), .[1 , ]))  %>% 
  slice(-1) %>%
  janitor::clean_names() %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = - x1_ciudad) %>%   
  separate(name, into = c("ano", "categoria"), sep = "_") 

datos <- datos %>%  
  mutate(ano = rep(c(2000,2000,2001,2001,2002,2002),length(levels(as.factor(dadtos$x1_ciudad))))) %>% 
  fill(ano)


datos
```